# Git Hub pages page build failure related to not properly initialized submodule

Tags: github, jekyll

Upon pushing an update to my gh-pages remote branch, i received an email from github, “Page build failure”.

> The submodule ‘myGitHubUser.github.io’ was not properly initialized
>   with a ‘.gitmodules’ file.

Providing link, https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule/

Following instruction in this link i tried,

```
git submodule init
```

Which returned,

> No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path
>   ‘myGitHubUser.github.io'

During my research, i found, https://support.deployhq.com/articles/common-deployment-errors/no-submodule-mapping-found

Which explains,

> This occurs when the repository is using a submodule that has had no
>   mapping reference to the source repository created for it. The mapping
>   needs to be entered into a .gitmodules file inside the repository you
>   are using.

But at this point i’ve gone further down the rabbit hole than i can keep track of. Can you explain what is going on here at a high level?

Comment: Do you remember adding a submodule, or did someone else do it?

Comment: @Tim - My repo is based on a cloned Jekyll repository, if that helps.

Comment: Suggestion:start over. Download your repo, delete it and create it again. Then push the content back. This isn't probably the "right" way, but most likely the fastest.

Comment: @Virtua - Tried again. Update: as soon as i push to github the first time (without making changes to jekyll), i get the email error.

Comment: Hmm. Odd.... If you want, give me your repo url and I'll take a look and see what I find. :)

Comment: @Virtua - Here's whats happening, the /jekyll-portfolio-x i'm cloning is acting as a sub-module, so when i push everything back to github from my workspace's root-directory, it doesn't push the submodule's contents.
And the submodule just ends up being a blank/locked folder with no contents, in github.
I'm able to push its contents by cd'ing into the submodule before pushing to github, but then the sub-module's /folder doesn't get pushed, and jekyll kindof breaks because references in jekyll template are setup like /jekyl-portfolio/css/file.css. So i need that top folder.Any ideas? :)

Comment: To be honest I'm not good with modules and submodules... So I really would need access to your files to be able to help you. Or I would try at least... I'm thinking how could that be done. Does your remote repo have some content? Is it private?

Comment: Do you have some sort of backup or all the files live at the same folder you pushed/cloned to/from GitHub?

Comment: If you have a Jekyll project untouched by git would be easier. Otherwise you'd need to view the `.git` folder within your local directory and try to exclude it, or select all the contents but this git folder to be able to move your files to a new folder. The thing is, as far as I know this is a hidden folder and I don't remember how to set the hidden folders to be displayed. I did it to my PC once and never changed that again....

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want to expose your repo here, you can send me a link through my contact form at https://virtuacreative.com.br/en/

Comment: I could try to take a look tomorrow and see if I can help. ;)

Comment: Tried some small variation (among many) and now its working! Don't know what caused it though.